# Visual Studio: "Unable to find symbol file" in CPU Usage window when debugging project

Tags: visual-studio, profiler, debug-symbols

In Visual Studio when I run CPU profiling via Diagnostic Tools -> CPU Usage -> Start CPU Profiling and click on a function of the project I’m trying to debug in the “Call Tree” view, it states: “Unable to find symbol file, change symbol file locations to specify correct search paths.”
But when I switch over to the Modules window, I can see that the corresponding modules were loaded correctly.

In the Call Tree view, all functions from the project I’m debugging are listed as “ManagedModule”, while functions from other projects in the solution have the correct module name.

Things I’ve tried:

- Clean & rebuild entire solution
- Deleting all “bin” & “obj” folders and rebuild
- Disabling all filters in Diagnostic Tools -> CPU Usage (Just My Code, Native Code are disabled, all threads and categories are selected)
- Disabling “Just My Code” in Debug -> Options -> General
- Tick "Enable Native Debugging" in the launch profile
- Right clicking on a function the Call Tree Viewer and selecting “Load all Symbols”
- Add the project output folder to the symbol file locations in Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

EDIT: Doing CPU profiling via the Performance Profiler works fine with all modules showing their expected name and the code snippets showing up, but I would still prefer if I could do the same thing via the diagnostic tools instead (as I can make use of breakpoints there)